# How to display Factor values in plots?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, ggally, exploratory

When plotting variables of data type factor in R, the Y-axis graph shows the factor levels (i.e numbers), not the name of factors especially when plotting using `pairs()` function. Is there any way to display the names of the factors at both axes?

I have tried converting variable to character using `as.character()`, but it didn't work because R throws an error. As an example below code produces attached image

> library(ISLR)
>
> pairs(Wage)

Variables like jobclass, health are factors and I want graph to display name of the factors instead of numbers.
Cannot post images due to low reputation.

Comment: what plot are you referring to? scatter plot or bar chart? keep in mind that scatter plot is NOT for categorial variables.

Comment: You you please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that generates the error?

Comment: @Swastik According to `?pairs` `x: the coordinates of points given as numeric columns of a
          matrix or data frame.  Logical and factor columns are
          converted to numeric in the same way that ‘data.matrix’ does.`

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use a scatter plot for categorial variables. Instead, you should use a box plot. For example, `boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species ,data=iris)`

Comment: Is there a way to plot boxplot simultaneously for all variables? I am doing this at very initial stage of exploratory analysis. It is just about displaying values at y-axis not any additional feature, I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggpairs()` function from `GGally` can produce the graphs along with colours and factor names. The downside is it is considerably slower than `pairs()`

```
library(GGally)
library(ISLR)
attach(Wage)
ggpairs(Wage[,c("education","jobclass","health","wage")], colour="race")
```

Comment: `attach`ing is a bad habit in general, and in this particular example it saves *very* little typing if any.